# How to use Column Filter in react-bootstrap-table-next?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have following widgets which represents categories form the data in the table:
[image]

The flow is when a user clicks on one of the widgets the table should show data of that category only.

So far I have implemented following:

```
 const columns = [
 { 
  ....
  dataField: "Category", 
  formatter: formatCategory,
  text: "Category",
  sort: true,
  filter: textFilter({
    getFilter: (filter) => {
      // nameFilter was assigned once the component has been mounted.
      categoryFilter = filter;
    }
  })
  ....
}
```

Handle Clicking Event on Button and Passing the category:

```
const handleWidgetClick = (category) => {
   categoryFilter = category;

   // When I am doing something like this I am getting Uncaught Error
   // categoryFilter is not a Function
   categoryFilter(category) 
};
```

I have followed this [example](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Column%20Filter&selectedStory=Programmatically%20Text%20Filter&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel).

I am not sure what/where I am doing something wrong. Please guide me through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<BootstrapTable
  hover
  bordered={false}
  bootstrap4
  keyField={"apps.App"}
  data={apps ? selectedCategory ?apps.filter((itm)=>{
    return itm.Category === selectedCategory
  }) :apps : no_Data}
  columns={columns}
  filter={ filterFactory() }
  noDataIndication={intl.formatMessage({ id: "GENERAL.NO_DATA" })}
/>
```

Comment: `import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";`

Comment: @yodellingbutters, that belongs in your answer, not down here.  Also, some explanation of this answer would make it better.